# Angular Hide the div with particular index

Tags: angular, typescript

New to typescript, I have to hide the div on which the user has clicked.

Below is my code:

```
<div class="tiles" *ngFor="let episode of episodes; let i = index" (click)="showDetails(i)" style="width:100px;height:100px;border:2px solid black">
  {{episode.title}}
</div>

import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular 6';
  showDiv:boolean = false;

episodes = [
    { title: 'Winter Is Coming', director: 'Tim Van Patten' },
    { title: 'The Kingsroad', director: 'Tim Van Patten' },
    { title: 'Lord Snow', director: 'Brian Kirk' },
    { title: 'Cripples, Bastards, and Broken Things', director: 'Brian Kirk' },
    { title: 'The Wolf and the Lion', director: 'Brian Kirk' },
    { title: 'A Golden Crown', director: 'Daniel Minahan' },
    { title: 'You Win or You Die', director: 'Daniel Minahan' },
    { title: 'The Pointy End', director: 'Daniel Minahan' }
  ];

  showDetails(i):void{
    this.showDiv = !this.showDiv;
  }
}
```

Total 8 divs will be populated with above code. So, as soon as the 1st div is clicked it should hide and other divs should take over its place, similarly when 2nd div is clicked it should hide (1st one should appear visible) and other divs should take over its place.

Answer (score 2):

The idea is have a variable "indexHidden", when indexHidden== i, you hidden the "div". But you can not do it over the same "div".

So, we use a ng-container https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#ng-container-to-the-rescue to do the *ngFor

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let episode of episodes; let i = index">
   <div *ngIf="i!=indexHidden" (click)="indexHidden=i" class="tiles"
      style="width:100px;height:100px;border:2px solid black">
      {{episode.title}}
   </div>
</ng-container>

//in your component.ts
indexHidden:number=-1 //At first equal=-1, so all episodes are showed
```

Comment: ++ for ng-container.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<div *ngFor="let episode of episodes; let i = index">
  <div class="tiles" *ngIf='i !== hide' (click)="hide = i" style="width:100px;height:100px;border:2px solid black">
    {{episode.title}} {{i}}
  </div>
</div>
```

## [Working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uzmd8z?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a one way to do that (no need for any variables in component. all logic in template:

```
<div class="tiles" *ngFor="let episode of episodes; let i = index" (click)="showDetails(i)" style="width:100px;height:100px;border:2px solid black">
   <span #itm [hidden]="itm[i]" (click)="itm[i] = true ">{{episode.title}}</span>
</div>
```

p.s. you can replace `[hidden]` to `*ngIf` so performance would increase in most cases

Answer (score 1):

Add attribute showDiv on each episodes's object.

Example:

```
episodes = [{showDiv: true, title: 'xxxxxx', ....}]
```

Comment: This is the most simple and easy solution.

Comment: Yes, this is a good solution but onclick of 1st tile if i set 'this.episodes[i].showDiv = false' and then I click on 2nd tile the second tile will disappear but 1st will also not show up coz it was set to false. This will make all the tile disappear. How to make the current tile disappear and set the previous ones to true?

Comment: One solution could be, every time you set this.episodes[i].showDiv = false, you can iterate over episodes and set all distinct to i to true.

Comment: this a simple solution but what if the back-end team is not ready to send "showDiv: true" in JSON response, in this case it will be a problem

Comment: This is part of frontend logic, not backend. In frontend you're free to change data structures sent by backend. Btw this isn't the only one solution.

Answer (score -1):

I will not use ngFor in this case , we almost implement carouse,
and you no longer need to use ngFor or ngIf and you keep looping the objects (episodes)

app.component.html

```
 <div class="tiles" (click)="showNext()" style="width:100px;height:100px;border:2px solid black">
  {{currentEpisode.title}}
 </div>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  public currentEpisode: any = {};
  currentIndex: number = -1;

  episodes = [
    { title: 'Winter Is Coming', director: 'Tim Van Patten' },
    { title: 'The Kingsroad', director: 'Tim Van Patten' },
    { title: 'Lord Snow', director: 'Brian Kirk' },
    { title: 'Cripples, Bastards, and Broken Things', director: 'Brian Kirk' },
    { title: 'The Wolf and the Lion', director: 'Brian Kirk' },
    { title: 'A Golden Crown', director: 'Daniel Minahan' },
    { title: 'You Win or You Die', director: 'Daniel Minahan' },
    { title: 'The Pointy End', director: 'Daniel Minahan' }
  ];

  showNext(): void {
    this.currentIndex = (this.currentIndex + 1) == this.episodes.length ? 0 : this.currentIndex + 1;
    this.currentEpisode = this.episodes[this.currentIndex];

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.showNext()
  }
}
```

[Working example at stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s3vnf7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)